# Laravel Multiple Uploading Only Inserts 20 into DB

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I have created an API that will allow multiple image uploads, but when I try to upload more than 20 it will only insert twenty records and no more at a time. It will save the full amount on the server. There are no errors thrown and nothing in the logs indicating an issue.

The table I'm saving to (events_images) looks like:

```
id, event_id, title, path, size, extension, description, created_at, updated_at
```

Here is my Laravel script:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $id = $request->id;
    $images = $request->file('image');
    $count = 0;

    // confirm that files exists in the request
    if(empty($images)):
        return response()->json(['error' => 'no images exist'], 500);
    endif;

    // validate image(s) before we store to db to make sure there are no failures
    // TODO : add to validation
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'image.*' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png'
    ]);

    if($validator->fails()):
        return response()->json(['error' => 'upload failed, please make sure you are uploading a jpeg, jpg, or png'], 500);
    endif;

    // store images in DB and upload
    foreach($images as $image):
        $title = Uuid::uuid1();
        $extension = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $path = $title . '.' . $extension;
        $size = $image->getClientSize();
        $description = NULL;           

        // store in db
        EventsImage::Create([
            'title' => $title,
            'path' => $path,
            'extension' => $extension,
            'size' => $size,
            'description' => $description,
            'event_id' => $id
        ]);

        // save to filesytem
        $raw = Storage::disk('media')->put('events' . '/' . $id . '/' . $path, file_get_contents($image));

        // create and store thumb
        $thumb = Image::make($image)->resize(150, null, function ($constraint) {
             $constraint->aspectRatio();
        });
        Storage::disk('media')->put('events' . '/' . $id . '/t_' . $path, (string) $thumb->encode());

        // create and store medium
        $medium = Image::make($image)->resize(300, null, function ($constraint) {
             $constraint->aspectRatio();
         });
        Storage::disk('media')->put('events' . '/' . $id . '/m_' . $path, (string) $medium->encode());

        // create and store full size
        // TODO : if smaller than 1920 then don't do anything
        $full = Image::make($image)->resize(1920, null, function ($constraint) {
             $constraint->aspectRatio();
        });
        Storage::disk('media')->put('events' . '/' . $id . '/' . $path, (string) $full->encode());

        $count++;
        
    endforeach;

    $event = Event::with('EventImages')->find($id);
    
    return response()->json(['success' => true, 'message' => $count . ' images have been uploaded successfully', 'data' => $event], 200);
}
```

I have looked at the data being sent to the API and everything is there, and all the files save to the disc. I have also commented out the file saving logic to see if it's a time thing and it still would only insert 20 records.

Is there some type of limit setting? Is it because I'm using a loop to save one record at a time?

## Edit

I am using Postman and Angular 4 and getting the same result. I upload more than 20 images, and Laravel only sees 20.

Comment: `$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'image.*' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png'
    ]);` i have a feeling this will check the http mime type of the image.. Which you can bypas and upload other files.

Comment: Test this: `$image = new EventsImage([...]); var_dump($image->save());`

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir I did what you suggested and I only see 20 coming in. I noticed in Chromes Dev Tools I can see all images being sent.. strange. Does Laravel has a setting that limits the payload? Not sure why it would, but thought I'd ask.

Comment: My guess is that PHP's `max_file_uploads` setting in php.ini is still set to the default ot 20.

Comment: @Graham that's right

Comment: @Graham go ahead and make answer

Comment: Please check and update throttle in your kernal.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might need to change your PHP settings to allow for larger uploads. PHP has limits on file upload size, POST size etc

Go to : `/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini`  or `/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini` or if you are using Apache `/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini`and change these values.

```
post_max_size = 125M 

upload_max_filesize = 100M 

max_file_uploads = 20
```

to a higher value. where `post_max_size` is the maximum size of an entire POST `upload_max_filesize` is the max size of an individual size and `max_file_uploads` is the maximum limit of files you can upload at a time.